# Evaluation of a GLS fit

Tags: generalized-least-squares

My first post in this useful community. Ive been trying to use GLS methods in non-linear mixed effects models and have found this post, [Prediction with GLS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14426/prediction-with-gls) extremely informative and helpful. 
Some of my questions are probably more of a follow up to the above post which discusses the predictive capability of GLS. Below I will state my question and give a brief description of why I would like to know more.

- How does one evaluate a GLS fit for a **real dataset** as compared to a regular fit?

Using simulations I could show that GLS is robust to error model mis-specification, especially when the data is sparse or there is deviation from normality (heavy-tailed distribution or time-varying distribution of residuals). For a simulated model, there is decreased bias and improved precision of the model parameters in a gls fit  compared to the regular nlme fit. However, I don't understand how would I evaluate my gls fit for a real dataset as compared to a regular fit. Standard errors/Goodness of Fit/etc..?

- At which stage of model building does one test a GLS fit?

Carrol and Ruppert state that when there is enough evidence of heteroschedasticity of your variance, then GLS estimators are very efficient. I obviously could see that in simulations studies, but how do I justify a better fit in a **real dataset** when the parameter estimates of the model from a gls fit are not very different from those obtained after a regular fit (even though the gls estimator is more efficient). This obviously comes back to the question, why (or actually why not) use GLS estimation at all.

- The estimation of residual variance parameters is independent of response prediction. T/F?

If the variance changes with your predictions (e.g. a constant CV model), is my understanding of the above statement correct that the estimation of the residual variance parameters is independent of model prediction of responses (or vice-versa). I believe this is the basic principle behind GLS.

- Can anyone suggest good references whether gls is design dependent ( both structure and density of observations)
- Any comments on gls performance/robustness for variable selection. Given bullet 3 above, can we expect gls to be  more sensitive in picking up predictors for a response variable.

Thanks in advance,

VJ

Comment: Any thoughts would be appreciated !