# How to calculate the regression variance for a GLS model?

Tags: r, variance, residuals, prediction, generalized-least-squares

I need to calculate the regression variance ($\sigma^2$) in order to estimate both the confidence intervals and the prediction intervals in a gls regression analysis.  For the analysis, the covariance matrix ($V$) of the response variable ($y$) is known in advance, and so I use it directly as the weighting matrix (=$V^{-1}$) in the gls regression analysis.

The regression variance is a weighted sum of the residual error:
$\sigma^2 = \frac{ (Y – X\beta)^T C^{-1} (Y – X\beta)}{n – p}$

My question/problem is how to determine the weighting matrix $C^{-1}$?  $C$ cannot be set equal to $V$ since (according to the above equation) $C$ must be dimensionless while $V$ has the same units as $\sigma^2$.

Based on my reading of the literature and available texts, it seems that $C$ is the correlation matrix and is a scaled or normalized form of the covariance matrix $V$.  i.e., $V = Var(\epsilon^2) = \sigma^2 C$.  But my problem is that $\sigma^2$ is not yet known, and so I need another way find $C$ from $V$.

R functions such as gls() will compute the regression variance (if I knew how gls() does this, it would answer my question).  However I cannot use gls() in this case since I am specifying a user-defined covariance (weighting) matrix, and gls() only accepts a limited set of specific correlation structures.

In fact a possible solution can be found in this [earlier post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14426/prediction-with-gls) where an equation for the SEE (or sigma2) for a GLS regression was cited :

GLS calc of SEE: sqrt( sum( ( residuals from linear model) ^ 2 * glsWeight ) ) / sum( glsWeight ) * length( glsWeight ) / residualDegreeFreedom )

However I am unable to ascertain the validity of this equation and cannot find its source reference.

Answer (score 2):

You are a bit off I think because the formula for epsilon you seem to use relies on the neccesity to decompose your error variance into a constant term ($\sigma^2$) and a correlation term $\Omega$, which is the $C$ in your post. You actually have to use this $C$ as a weight for the regression. Let me explain.

It is assumed you know $\Omega$, otherwise you have to do FGLS instead. The formula you have is a result of a transformed model. First, let's look at our GLS estimators:
Under the assumption that $V[\epsilon|X]=\sigma^2\Omega$ you can transform the model and estimate the following
$$\widehat{\beta}^{GLS} = [X'\Omega^{-1}X]^{-1}X'\Omega^{-1}y$$
This, generally, is a BLUE estimator under the assumptions.
Which has, under the above and usual assumptions this variance
$$V[\widehat{\beta}^{GLS}] = \sigma^2[X'\Omega^{-1}X]^{-1} $$
Since you know $\Omega$, you can now calculate everything and estimate the $\sigma^2$. To understand how have a look at how the GLS estimator is reached.
You reached this result by applying a matrix $P$ to the model formula as such
$$PY = PX\beta + P\epsilon$$
What is P? If you know omega, you can calculate the $P$ (Cholesky decomposition) with
$$ P'P = \Omega^{-1}$$
And then you have a consistent estimator in
$$ \widehat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{(P\hat{\epsilon}^{OLS})'P\hat{\epsilon}^{OLS}}{n-k} \\
=  
\frac{ \hat{\epsilon}'^{OLS} \Omega^{-1} \hat{\epsilon}^{OLS}}{n-k} $$
This is the formula you have listed, but it implies a possible decomposition  $V[\epsilon|X]=\sigma^2\Omega$. Note how it uses the residuals of OLS. This is because of said existence of a transformed and non-transformed model.

You said you used $V[Y]=V$ as weight for GLS. Can you tell us the exact formula? Is it
$$\widehat{\beta}^{GLS} = [X'V^{-1}X]^{-1}X'V^{-1}y$$
?
In that case you used $V$ instead of $C$. You mentioned that you think $V[\epsilon]=V$ and $V=\sigma^2C$ (I assume this is what you mean).
You could go ahead and plug in $V$ instead of $C$.
But of course this is not actually correct because $V$ is not equal to $C$ as you discovered.
This seems to be your problem.

If you know nothing about the composition of your error terms, you just can't get to that decomposition and the $C$ you need. That is the 'point' of GLS. It takes advantage of a known correlation structure $\Omega$ or $C$ to regain BLUE estimators.
So the equation you can not validate is the result of said transformed model. For this you also need to have your $\Omega$ or $C$ as you called it and by that the $P$ to transform the model.
If you do not have this, use FGLS instead.

Comment: *You could go ahead and plug in $V$ instead of $C$. But of course this is not actually correct because $V$ is not equal to $C$ as you discovered …*
In fact this is not true. In the equation for $\beta^GLS$ any scaling factor applied to $V$ (in the equation that you showed) will cancel.  Thus $V$ or $C$ or any $V$ scaled by any constant will work and yield the same answer for $\beta$.  In my case, I used $V$ to compute $\beta$, in the absence of knowing $C$ and $\sigma^2$.

Comment: *If you know nothing about the composition of your error terms, you just can't get to that decomposition and the C you need. That is the 'point' of GLS …*
For my particular problem I know $V$ but not $C$.  This is because my empirical measurements of my response variable $y$ include estimates of their variances and covariances.  (It is somewhat unusual to know $V$ a priori and not $C$, but nevertheless quite possible, if $y$ represents instrumental measurements or values taken from a complex survey design for example).

Comment: *And then you have a consistent estimator in …*
I would like to clarify a point that you made the first part of your response (before being able to evaluate it).  The equation for $\hat{\sigma }^2$ is expressed in terms of $\hat{\epsilon}^{OLS}$.  I do not believe this is correct.  In fact $\hat{\epsilon}^{OLS}$ should be replaced by simply $\hat{\epsilon}$, where the latter are in fact the GLS residuals.  This follows from examination of the preceding equations where $\epsilon $ represents $\epsilon^{GLS}$.  (In fact $\epsilon^{OLS} = P\epsilon$)

Comment: I would very be interested in your follow-up to my comments ...

Comment: Post 1: It is true that the unbiasedness is not in question when using any weighting factor. It is not relevant to your question because you are looking for the covariances. The GLS formula in question results from the transformed model with the $P$

Comment: Post 3: It is in fact the OLS estimator. This is also the case in your formula(s) for $\sigma^2$. This is a bit confusing because the transformed model is not the OLS model, it is the GLS model.$P\epsilon$ is the GLS error term which is homoscedastic, whereas $\epsilon$ is not. You can use your GLS residuals but then you can do away with the weighting matrix. In that case using $\hat{\epsilon}^{GLS}$ without the $C^{-1}$ gives a good estimate of $\sigma^2$. Using the $C$ in that formula is a direct result of the transformed model and is equivalent to using the GLS residuals in the first place.

Comment: Post 2: What do you know about the distribution of the $X$? I mean you could try to find out about your error terms by using the fact that $Y = f(X,\epsilon)$. But remember that the objective of GLS is to negate a systematic component in the $\epsilon$ by transforming the model into a model with homoscedastic and uncorrelated error terms. So if you can not separate these effects, you can not transform the model and regain BLUE. What I'd like to know is why you think the use of $V$ instead of $C$ as weight accomplishes this? I dunno maybe it does but I don't see it right now.

Comment: Followup to first Post: You also assume that V is proportional to C? Is this necessarily the case? In your previous answer you indicated that you believe you were able to use $V$ to get estimators because proportional/constants cancel out. For this to work, once again, the multiplication with $V$ needs to result in the transformed model. This implies proportion between $V$ and $C$. The issue is that GLS is not a way to find $C$, it is a way to use it. If I understand your issue correctly, I don't think your knowledge of $V$ helps in this case.

Comment: Post 1 reply:
*It is true that the unbiasedness is not in question when using any weighting factor.*
 Agreed.

*It is not relevant to your question because you are looking for the covariances.*
I am not sure if I understand this second sentence.  I am looking for the regression error $\sigma^2$, but I know the covariances (of the response variable $y$).

Comment: Post 3 reply:
I think that here we agree and that I was confused only about the notation that was used:

$\epsilon = \epsilon^{OLS}$ and are the heteroskedastic (and correlated) residuals in the untransformed coordinates.

$\epsilon^{GLS} = P\epsilon$ and are the homoscedastic (and uncorrelated) residuals in the transformed coordinates.

Correct?

Comment: Post 2 reply a:
*But remember that the objective of GLS is to negate a systematic component in the ϵ by transforming the model into a model with homoscedastic and uncorrelated error terms.*
Agreed.

Comment: Post 2 reply b:
*What I'd like to know is why you think the use of V instead of C as weight accomplishes this?*
As I mentioned, $V$ is available from empirical measurements which is why I use it.  It makes sense to weight the regression by the variances of the response variable $y$ and to account for the correlation between them.
As discussed, the GLS regression coefficients can be readily calculated using $V$ as $V$ and $C$ are related by a constant scaling factor that does not affect the equation for $\beta$. Where further information ($C$) is needed, is in the estimation of $\sigma^{2}$.

Comment: Do you actually have the distribution of $y$, or do you just have empirical values? Because of the latter is the case, I think you need to use FGLS. Your initial question was how to get to $C$. The answer is pretty much that $C$ is the prerequisite to using GLS - which is a way to utilize knowledge of the systemic component in $\epsilon$. You use an additional knowledge to transform the model. Knowledge of values of $y$ does not hold that information. Frankly, I think you can not use GLS. If you are sure about a systematic relationship in $\epsilon$, FGLS can give you good results.

Comment: This confirms it imo. GLS is not what you need. You are missing the systematic relationship information to use GLS. Use FGLS. Once again, the covariances of $y$ are a function of $X$ and $\epsilon$. As such you still only have $\epsilon$, at best. You are missing information to calculate either sigma OR $C$. To view it differently: You do not have enough information to transform the model as above. Yes, you have unbiased estimators using either OLS or the GLS formula, but they are not EFFICIENT. You are missing the transformed model by knowing either $C$,$P$ or $\sigma^2$.

Comment: You can't chat yet (need more points) and they don't like these kind of conversations here, because it clutters up the page or something. Besides, I gotta go now. If you have further questions and no one answers here feel free to write me at einsdrei at gmail dot com I will try to answer if I can.