# How to use error term in AR (2) model for predicting future values?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arma

We use turbidity to estimate suspended-sediment concentration (SSC)- our data was serially correlated. We ran an ARMA process and ended up with a AR (2) model. Our equation in log form is:

estlogi(SSC) = 1.35149 + 0.785099logi(Turbidity) - 0.00095 + 0.7492ei-1+ 0.2052ei-2

How can we input the ei-1 & ei-2 values in real time, that is, how do we enter residuals for current or future values when our turbidity/SSC data pairs are in the past (2010 to 2011). Someone did suggest an R script that will estimate K steps ahead for a specified ARMA model and past data- does anyone know this script?

Comment: Various software packages provide a machine readable file which could be easily converted to an r script. This file is based upon the model that was developed but is generic nature and useful to cover all univariate and causal time series models. You can approach SAS/SPSS or AUTOBOX and ask them to provide you with an example of this useful output.

Comment: You say the model is an AR(2) but you talk about entering residuals? What precisely is e1-1 ? Is that SSC in the prior period ? . It is possible to restate your Transfer Function (armax model) BUT I would have to have the actual data that you used to form this model . Are all variables in log form ?

Comment: Your equation does not describe ARMA model. You have a regression model with AR(p) disturbances. This means that for forecasting you can employ best linear unbiased prediction for GLS. This answer might help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14442/2116

Comment: I'm not convinced this question should be closed as off-topic - there seems to be a statistical issue at the heart of this, it isn't just a request for code.